# Store Datepicker Date Value to Database Birthdate Column in C# ( C sharp )

Tags: datetimepicker

Hey I want to Fetch the date from the date picker and add that date into my database birthdate column
soo plzzz help me out...

here Form View
and Grid View

just tell me syntax how to store the date value in Database birthdate column!
plzzz give me solution in C#.net only...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WinForms: The datepicker has a property called "Value" and it is of DateTime data type. Use that.

Web Forms: if you are using JQuery, just do

```
var date = $("#myDateControl").val();
```

Then how you store the value depends on what database you are using (Sql, Oracle, etc) and whether you are using Entity Framework (or other ORM) or not... give more details if you want a more thorough answer.

**EDIT**

Based on your comments, I would do something like this:

```
using (var connection - new SqlConnection("my connection string"))
{
    using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        command.CommandText = string.Format("INSERT INTO Stu_inf(Enrollno, Firstname, Lastname, Birthdate) VALUES ('{0}', '{1}', '{2}', '{3}')", txtEnrollno.Text, txtFname.Text, txtLname.Text, mtxtBdate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
        connection.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        connection.Close();
    }
}
```

I wrote this all from memory, so you may get a small syntax error or something.. but that's the idea... hope it helps

Comment: I m using SQL Server 
and i want only for Windows Forms

actually i put the Datetime picker
for user
user select one Date 
then I want to add that Date in Data Base Birthday column



String Query = "insert into Stu_info(Enrollno,Firstname,Lastname,Birthdate,) Values(" +txtEnrollno.Text+ " , '" +txtFname.Text+ "','" +txtLname.Text+ "','" +mtxtBdate.Text+ "' ")";

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Query, conn);
            conn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();

Comment: now this i m writing my code but not working....bcoz i can't use
mbate.text  bcoz it is date time picker control that's why

sooo plzzz help  me Out

Comment: I updated the answer above. Please accept it as "answer" if it helps.

Comment: mtxtBdate.Value = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells["Birthdate"].Value.ToString();

i want this on data Grid view..
this type of syntax use in all other textboxs..
but now how to use this datepicker control syntax..
this sytax is wrong
plzz tell me write